# Proper way to calling select.select() in threaded server

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, vpn, tunnel

I am trying to write a VPN server,that multiple clients can connect to each other on a virtual network.
So i need a threaded server to send and receive data to/from clients concurrently.
A tunnel interface may be created for each client, that represents the client's virtual interface on server.

I have two solutions for using `select()` function to read/write from/to tunnel on server:

1. Using a single thread that calls `select([tun0,tun1,tun2],[tun0,tun1,tun2],[])` function for all Tunnels, and using buffers to hold-up traffic.
2. Calling `select([tun0],[tun0],[])` function separately on specific client's thread.

My question is: which way is better ?

Comment: Why are you even threading with select ;D

Comment: Are you mean i do not need to use select() function in threaded server manner ?

Comment: I mean you don't need threading in a proper event driven application... 
Have you considered twisted?

Comment: Yes i am using twisted. but twsited makes a thread for each client,isn't true?

Comment: No. Twisted is event driven at its core, it creates an instance of each Protocol class, then when that event happens (usually tracked by `epoll` or other) it calls the method associated with the event.

Comment: Wow, thanks, you mean all of my codes on protocols runs on one thread? so i need to call select() one time, and raise events on twisted core?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27910/discussion-between-pylover-and-jakob-bowyer)

Comment: @JakobBowyer if the OP wasn't using twisted, would you say it's still surprising to use select in a multithreaded application? Like if he blocked one of the threads using a blocking select, would it be a bad idea?

Comment: Seems weird mixing concerns, @max you would just let the thread block

Comment: @JakobBowyer ah, right. Somehow I imagined each thread might take care of multiple sockets (so even for blocking IO it needs to use `select`). But now that I think about, I don't see a reason for a thread to deal with multiple sockets.

Comment: You don't need threads at all :) look at asyncio